# Import failure of a module in PyCharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, python-import

I am using Python to write various small scripts on Windows10.
I want to use module Pillow in PyCharm to manage a picture library.
My piece of code starts like this :

```
import os
import Pillow
```

When I run it, I get the following error message:

> "C:\Users\steph\PycharmProjects\Carte SD Alex\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "C:\Users\steph\PycharmProjects\Carte SD Alex\Originals requested list.py"
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\steph\PycharmProjects\Carte SD Alex\Originals requested list.py", line 3, in 
>       import Pillow
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Pillow'
>   Process finished with exit code 1

I tried to import the Pillow module from the user interface (menu File - Settings, then Project: my>Project - Python interpreter, + on the right). I find Pillow, then click "Install package".

An error occurs and I get the following message :

> Command ""C:\Users\steph\PycharmProjects\Carte SD
>   Alex\venv\Scripts\python.exe" -u -c "import setuptools,
>   tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\steph\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\Pillow\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
>   '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install
>   --record C:\Users\steph\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-br8j8tkm\install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers "C:\Users\steph\PycharmProjects\Carte SD
>   Alex\venv\include\site\python3.8\Pillow"" failed with error code 1 in
>   C:\Users\steph\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\Pillow\

I have the complete log available if that can help.
I have search many forums and found different causes and ways of solving. I tried them without success.
I have checked with the interpreter itself but it works.

Command line :

> C:\Users\steph>pip install Pillow Requirement already satisfied:
>   Pillow in
>   c:\users\steph\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages
>   (7.1.1)

Anyway, if I try to use the module in python directly, il fails with the same error code :

> C:\Users\steph>python Python 3.8.2 (tags/v3.8.2:7b3ab59, Feb 25 2020,
>   23:03:10) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32 Type "help",
>   "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>
> > > > import Pillow Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Pillow'

I have only one version of Python installed.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: If you're using PyCharm it has probably created a virtual environment for you. (that is what the `venv` in the path name refers to)

Comment: Pillow is a fork of PIL. I think all the modules are still in the PIL namespace. Have you tried `import PIL`? See [the tutorial](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/tutorial.html).

Comment: Thanks Peter. I tried "import PIL" but it fails. I tried to add it in PyCharm as explained in the original post (same procedure as installing the Pillow package : File - Settings, etc.) but it fails immediatly.

Answer (score 0):

While importing Pillow, you should import it by name PIL, not Pillow.

```
import PIL
```

Thats it.

Comment: Thanks Mandar. Pillow is a recommended fork from PIL for user-friendlyness. So I would prefer to use Pillow. Anyway, I tried to use PIL instead of Pillow as you suggest, and it does not even load. So I am still stuck.